# Selecting all images in a <td> tag and disabling them

Tags: asp.net, html, css, css-selectors

My HTML looks something like this:

```
<table class="disabled">
   <tr>
      <td>
         <input blah blah>

      </td>
      <td>
         <img id="reallyLongASP.NetID" etcetc/>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

In all  with a class indicated as "disabled", I want to set visibility: hidden on the `<img>`.  I can disable using the crazy id ASP.Net gives, but would like to do a general statement that affects every control in the `<table>`

Thanks for the help in advance,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you'll just want to select all images within tables having the class specified:

```
table.disabled img { visibility:hidden }
```

Comment: Thanks, was way overthinking this.

Comment: @Cen No worries, it happens to us all :)